# Pie Chart SSRS percentages

Tags: sql, reporting-services, pie-chart

I have made a pie chart and added percentages to it. Only thing is its showing `0.0%` and making it really hard to read.

My expression currently is

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Misc.Value = "Quoted Bes Elec", 1, 0))
```

I would like the values that are 0.0% not to show in the pie chart.

Comment: Can you share an image of your current report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `0` you can use `Nothing`

With this dataset

```
 Misc
 ----
 Quoted Bes Elec
 A
```

Then setting the expression for this series in the chart to be

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!Misc.Value = "Quoted Bes Elec", 1, Nothing))
```

Gives the chart

[image]

Is this the behaviour you require?

Comment: Hi I'm not over sure until I get in the office tomorrow.

Comment: My pie chart is made up of 3 expressions, but at time one will bring back a 0 value. So I only want to show the percentage of the other 2 if that makes sense